# Haskell: Replacing element with a given key in an association list

Tags: list, haskell

I've got to make a function which is given a key (as a `String`), a value (as a `String`) and an association list of keys and values (as `[(String, String)]`). The function is meant to add the key/value pair on to the end of the list, and, if the key is already present in the list with an associated value, delete the old value.

I've tried using `lookup` on the key and association list, but I'm not sure what to do with the output - the output type of the `lookup` function is `Maybe String`, and I can't seem to do list functions (like dropping elements) on it. Is there any way I can look through the list and delete any list element with a given key without knowing the value associated with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably write a recursive function that takes the new key/value-pair and the existing list as parameters, and loops through the list to generate a new list with the new value inserted. For each list element you check if the key is the same as the one you want to insert. If it's different you keep that old element, if it's the same you add the new item instead of the old one. If you reach the end of the list without finding the key you just insert the new item there at the end.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple function that does what you want.  It takes the new key value pair and puts that at the front of the given assoc list with that key filtered out.

```
addOrReplace :: Eq k => k -> v -> [(k, v)] -> [(k, v)]
addOrReplace key value assoc = (key,value):(filter ((key /=).fst) assoc)
```

The function `fst` is defined as:

```
fst (first,second) = first
```

`filter` takes a predicate and a list, and returns the list with only those elements that satisfy the predicate.

Edit: Split the key value pair in the parameters for addOrReplace as Tom suggests.

Comment: I would prefer to pass the key and value as separate arguments instead of pairing them. That way its easier to partially apply the function without having to `curry` it.

Answer (score 4):

In Haskell, we often use the `Maybe` datatype when we're not sure whether we'll get a value or nothing at all as a result. It's equivalent to a nullable type in a more traditional language such as Java.

`Maybe` is defined as follows:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

That is, the value can either be `Nothing` or `Just a`, where `a` is the object you were looking for. For example, if you were searching for the string `"foo"` using the `lookup` function, and you had a `("foo", "bar")` tuple inside your list, you'd get the result `Just "bar"`. However, if you looked up `"xyzzy"`, you'd get `Nothing`.

We can take the `Maybe` value and turn it into something more useful using the `maybe` function (confusing names, I know - the function is all lowercase). It's defined as follows:

```
maybe default f (Just a) = f a
maybe default f Nothing  = default
```

The first parameter is a default value. This is what we get back if we have `Nothing`. Otherwise, we get the function `f` applied to `a`, where `a` is the thing we want. If you just want `a` back, you can pass the `id` function as `f`:

```
maybe default id (Just a) = id a
```

Helpfully, `id a = a`.

If you want to continue using your current `lookup` plan, this is how you'll get something useful out of it. I personally favour sth's method though - it'd be easier on the processor.